# How to get a file from the backend withou getting it JSON-parsed

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I’m able to get an xlsx file from my rails backend with a GET-Request to “/companies/export_xslx”, now I’m facing the problem of getting the file passed the JSON parser. For every request the console shows “JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data”.

This is my setup:

```
//company model ...
exportXlsx: function() {
  const adapter = this.store.adapterFor('company');
  return adapter.exportXlsx();
}

//adapters/company.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import TokenAuthorizerMixin from 'ember-simple-auth-token/mixins/token-authorizer';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(TokenAuthorizerMixin, {

  exportXlsx() {
    const url = 'companies/export_xlsx';
    return this.ajax(url, 'GET',
      { dataType: 'text',
         accepts: { xlsx: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
       } });
  }
});
```

I’ll try to alter the default accept header but the requests gets sent with “Accept: application/vnd.api+json”.

I already tried different approaches with “ember-custom-actions” or “ember-cli-file-saver”, they all failed with the JSON.parse… response.

Comment: It’s not JSON so parsing it as JSON seems like a mistake. Are you forced to use Ember Data facilities for interpreting the data? Could it be a `fetch` in the route instead? Or if you want to use Ember Data, you probably need a custom adapter that parses the Excel format and uses `pushPayload` to add it to the store.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I've found an other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I tackle the problem in the component with a download service:

```
// components/companies-download.js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({

  download: service(),

  actions: {

    downloadXlsx() {
      let url = `/companies/export_xlsx`;
      this.get('download').file(url);
    }

  }
});



// services/download.js
import Service from "@ember/service";
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({

  session: service(),

  file(url) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = () => {
      let [, fileName] = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/.exec(
        xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")
      );
      let file = new File([xhr.response], decodeURIComponent(fileName));
      let link = document.createElement('a');
      link.style.display = 'none';
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      link.download = file.name;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
      'Authorization',
      'Bearer ' + this.get('session.data.authenticated.token')
    );
    xhr.send();
  }
});
```